# Sharepoint 2016, calculated column isblank always returns false

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I am trying to compare 2 columns, but when i use ISBLANK it always returns false, even if the field is blank.

My formula:

[image: Formula]

My List

[image: List]

The column it checks

[image: Column]

As you can see, some of the fields are blank and some or not, but it always returns no. I have no clue as to why this is happening

Comment: Can you try `ISBLANK([TimeActualArrival])`? If that doesn't work then you might need to do something more like, `=IF(ISBLANK([My Column]), "Yes", "No")`

Comment: Changing the formula does not work. The thing is that it works on another view, but this specific list does not work. Is there any setting somewhere that might cause this behavior?

Comment: I have tried it myself so not sure why it’s not working. You do need the [] around the name of the column. Can you create a new column and instead of having it return as a string have it yes no and try them again with =ISBLANK([TimeActualArrival])

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well.  Something is probably wrong with the list itself and might need to be recreated.

In my case, I wasn't allowed to recreate the list.  So my solution was to check if there was an error in the field by using ISERR:

```
=IF(
    OR(
       ISBLANK([Date1])
       ,ISERR([Date1])
    )
    ,[Date2]
    ,[Date1]
 )
```